# using indirect.ext as value if true at IF-function

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-2010, worksheet

I want to know if there is the option to use indirect as an answer for an value of an logical test for example when the IF-function returns true.

I hope the example here explains it.

Example:
book 1 contains the following cells with data

```
a1=3

a2=4

a3=5

a4=6

let b1 say: IF(a1>3;"INDIRECT.ext(F:\analyse\[book 2.xlsx]sheet1'!a1";"INDIRECT.ext(F:\analyse\[book2.xlsx]sheet1'!a2")
```

book2 contains the following cells with data
a1 more
a2 less

I can't get this working while using "" It just returns the function as a string. Also [] and () wont work. Therefore I know I can put the data in the same book. But it will save a lot of time if this works.

Comment: should it be: `=IF(A1>3;INDIRECT.ext("F:\analyse\[book 2.xlsx]sheet1'!A1");INDIRECT.ext("F:\analyse\[book2.xlsx]sheet1'!A2")`? or little bit shorter: `=INDIRECT.ext("F:\analyse\[book 2.xlsx]sheet1'!A" & IF(A1>3,1,2))`

Comment: @simoco i have tried putting the formula in but it gives a ref error I am also pretty new with excell. Playing and understanding it now for a week. Can u explain:**=INDIRECT.ext("F:\analyse\[book 2.xlsx]sheet1'!A" & IF(A1>3,1,2))**

Comment: yeah, sorry missed quote sign `'`, try this: `=IF(A1>3;INDIRECT.ext("'F:\analyse\[book 2.xlsx]sheet1'!A1");INDIRECT.ext("'F:\analyse\[book2.xlsx]sheet1'!A2")`? or little bit shorter: `=INDIRECT.ext("'F:\analyse\[book 2.xlsx]sheet1'!A" & IF(A1>3,1,2))`

Comment: `Can u explain` - yes: `INDIRECT` takes string with address as parametr. `IF(A1>3,1,2)` returns `1` or `2`, so `"...'!A" & IF(A1>3,1,2)` concatenates two strings and you get either `"...'!A1"` or `"...'!A2"`

Comment: =IF(I3>3;INDIRECT.EXT("'F:\analyse\gewicht\[test.xlsx]sheet1'!A1");INDIRECT.EXT("'F:\analyse\gewicht\[test.xlsx]sheet1'!A2"))
This formula will still give a ref error